# Vega-Lite - Error in the scales of circles and lines

Tags: visualization, scale, vega-lite

I'm trying to use Vega-Lite to do a plot similar to a graph, where nodes are connected to other nodes by edges. The nodes vary in size according to a variable,while the edges width also vary.
The information for the nodes is stored in a different dataset than the information for the edges.

The problem is, once I try to plot everything together ("nodes" + "edges"), Vega-Lite is marking the size of the nodes very small (almost not visible). If I don't use the "size" for my edges plot, everything comes out normal.

Here is an example of what I'm doing (note that the notation is a bit different from native Vega-Lite, because I'm programming on Julia):

```
v1 = @vlplot(
    mark={:circle,opacity=1},
    x={μ[:,1],type="quantitative",axis=nothing},
    y={μ[:,2],type="quantitative",axis=nothing},
    width=600,
    height=400,
    size={μ_n,legend=nothing,type="q"})
v2 = @vlplot(
    mark={"type"=:circle,color="red",opacity=1},
    x={ν[:,1],type="quantitative",axis=nothing},
    y={ν[:,2],type="quantitative",axis=nothing},
    width=600,
    height=400,
    size={ν_m,legend=nothing,type="q"})
```

[image]

Then, when I create the visualization for the edges, and plot everything together:

```
v3 = @vlplot(
    mark={"type"=:line,color="black",clip=false},
    data = df,
    encoding={
    x={"edges_x:q",axis=nothing},
    y={"edges_y:q",axis=nothing},
    opacity={"ew:q",legend=nothing},
    size={"ew:q",scale={range=[0,2]},legend=nothing},
    detail={"pe:o"}},
    width=600,
    height=400
)
@vlplot(view={stroke=nothing})+v3+v2+v1
```

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?
(Note that the "scale" attribute is not the reason. Even if I remove it, the problem persists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering compound charts, Vega-Lite uses shared scales by default (see https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html): it looks like when your `size` scale is shared between the line and circle plots, it leads to poor results.

I'm not familiar with the `VegaLite.jl` syntax, but the JSON specification you'll want on the top-level chart is:

```
 "resolve": {"scale": {"size": "independent"}}
```